# .Net 4.5 Interpret Legal URI?

Tags: .net, string, c#-4.0, url, uri

I can place the following URI in a browser and it will take me to Google and it will process the request.

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=Hello%20on%2013.09.8888@2500:39:41%20as%20test%20number%2005
```

However,  Uri.TryCreate and Uri.IsWellFormedUriString both say that is not a legal URI.
What is the best way to parse this? It looks "legal" to my users...

Thanks.

Comment: `new Uri("http://www.google.com/search?q=Hello%20on%2013.09.8888@2500:39:41%20as%20test%20number%2005")` works fine for me

Comment: If that works, then why does TryCreate fail?

Comment: `Uri.TryCreate("http://www.google.com/search?q=Hello%20on%2013.09.8888@2500:39:41%20as%20test%20number%2005", UriKind.Absolute, out u)` also works

Comment: Both `Uri.TryCreate` and `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` works with this URL for me too. Either you use `UriKind.Relative` here, or you're trying to verify another URL.